# Cannot parse graph.facebook

Tags: android, parsing, android-parser

I've worked on getting a JSON object for retrieving information from a server and I successfully parsed it. But I have been given the task to parse the JSON object that we get from graph.facebook.com. But when I try to parse it, it shows an error like this

> error OAuthException (#210) Subject must be a page".

I don't know why I'm getting this error. Isn't it possible to get JSON from graph.facebook.com. [This](http://graph.facebook.com/fundamentalalvarado/?fields=albums.fields%28photos.fields%28source%29%29) page retrieves information in JSON. But I cannot parse it. My code to parse it goes like this.

Parser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
//          is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        System.out.print(jObj.toString());
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what can I do to solve this problem. I'm in very much need of it.

Comment: show us the URL your are hitting for json.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. Your are hitting with POST for GET type of URL. Change your HTTP POST to HttpGet.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: http://graph.facebook.com/fundamentalalvarado/?fields=albums.fields(photos.fields(source))

Comment: Read my second comment. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm posting it as an answer. Mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using HTTP Post for Get API.

Change your HTTP POST to HttpGet.

Regards